# WP Plugins install error - Installation failed: Download failed. cURL error 35

Tags: wordpress, curl, plugins

When I am going for download and install *[Jetpack by WordPress.com](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jetpack/)* plugins in my WP. There look error:

> **Installation failed: Download failed. cURL error 35: error:0D0890A1:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_verify:unknown message digest algorithm**.

Comment: Did you re-try? Maybe a connection failure happened

Comment: I did try again and again . But didn't work :(

Comment: Are you able to install other plugins? If you can install other plugins, then open a bug on that plugin, otherwise you have some problems with your server where your website is hosted (and this time you should open a ticket at your service provider)

Comment: Hmm... I am unable to install any kind of plugins :( . What type ticket should to open ??? Please suggest me....

Comment: Are you on localhost or on a web server?

Comment: Enter in your web server page and open a bug/ticket/question to your web server host and ask them to help you solve the issue. Maybe they made some configuration that can't let you download plugins

Comment: Thanks for help me :)

Comment: make sure you have curl enabled in your php settings

Comment: thanks for your suggestion

Comment: When operating on a `localhost` installation of Wordpress I found my firewall was blocking `wordpress.org` once this was whitelisted I no longer had this issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Edit the `/wp-includes/class-http.php` file
– change SSL as noted in code example below

```
‘decompress’ => true,
// ‘sslverify’ => true
‘sslverify’ => false,
‘sslcertificates’ => ABSPATH . WPINC . ‘/certificates/ca-bundle.crt’,
‘stream’ => false,
‘filename’ => null,
‘limit_response_size’ => null,
);
```

Answer (score 0):

`'ssl_verify' => false` to `'ssl_verify' => true`
at the location of `/wp-includes/class-wp-http.php` solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

From the website: https://curl.se/docs/caextract.html

1. Add latest version of `cacert.pem` file.
2. Move `cacert.pem` file to `wp-includes\certificates`.
3. Delete or remane the existing `wp-includes\certificates\ca-bundle.crt` file.
4. Rename `cacert.pem` to `ca-bundle.crt` after deleting the existing `ca-bundle.crt` file (which was deleted in the previous step to avoid any conflicts).

After installing the latest version of the certificate, the problem was solved for me.